# How can I calculate the cyclic (periodic) convolution?

Tags: convolution

I'd like to understand how to calculate the cyclic convolution as well as understand what that means exactly. How should I go about finding the output for various periods for a system?

I have an example:

$$
x(n) = 
\begin{cases}
n & \textrm{for} \quad 1 \leq n \leq 3\\ 0 &\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

$$
h(n) = 
\begin{cases}
n & \textrm{for} \quad 1 \leq n \leq 2\\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

If I perform the convolution, then I get the following values for $y(n)$:

$$y(2) = 1;\quad y(3) = 4;\quad y(4) = 7;\quad y(5) = 6$$

Now, if I want a period = 3, then:

$$x(n) = x(n+3k) \quad\textrm{and}\quad h(n) = h(n+3k)$$

At this point, I'm unsure of what to do to get values that correspond to a period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People generally define the cyclic convolution of *periodic* sequences
$x$ and $h$ of period $N$ as
$$y[n] = \sum_{m=0}^{N-1}x[m]h[n-m], n = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1.\tag{1}$$
Note that the above expression consists of $N$ different sums that
you have to compute, and if while computing any particular sum,
the value of $n-m$ is not in the range of numbers for which you
are given $h[\cdot]$, then you use the periodicity ($h[n-m] = h[n-m+N]$
or $h[n-m] = h[n-m-N]$) to get the argument into the range for which 
you know the value of $h[\cdot]$. 
Also, note that $(1)$ holds for *all* integers $n$, but we don't
need to *calculate* more than $N$ sums like $(1)$ because
$y[n]$ is *also* a periodic sequence of period $N$ and so we have
for any integer
$M$ that  $y[M] = y[M \bmod N]$ where, of course, $0 \leq M \bmod N \leq N-1$.

Exercise: **write out** the above formula **explicitly**, meaning
no summations, for $n = 0, 1, 2$ and proceed from there.  Go on;
you can do it. There are only three sums of three terms each.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it out.